# I need help decoding this: "Qhr nhrq lrvhf fs uoulfbye..."

Tags: cipher

I can't figure out how to decode it and everything I try for it doesn't work:

> Qhr nhrq lrvhf fs uoulfbye. Ln oenlos fs. Eedfiy. V mhuk... tuaw'm qhr pdmpwbrg: blreiefb

Comment: Where did you find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The [Boxentriq](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/vigenere-cipher) solver reveals that this is Vigenère with key XANADU, decrypting to
>  "The next level is horrible. It really is. Really. I mean... that's the password: horrible"
>  I figured that it was Vigenère from the two occurrences of QHR 48 letters apart, leading to likely key lengths of 6 and 8.